# Mongoose : .find() doesn't return any document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**EDIT :**
Duplicate of : [Mongoose find() not returning result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100328/mongoose-find-not-returning-result/23100950)

---

I'm new to nodejs and nosql db.. Today I'm creating an API which read my user collection with two entries :

[image: The collection (with two entries)]

The problem is that the result is an empty array :

[image: Result]

**Here is the code :**

The model :

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var UserModelSchema   = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    user_id:String,
    age:{ type: Number },
    status:String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserModelSchema);
```

app.js :

```
//...
var User     = require('./app/models/user');
//...
router.route('/users')
// get all the users 
.get(function(req, res) {
    User.find(function(err, users) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(users);
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183611/mongoose-always-returning-an-empty-array-nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to (even if not necessary) pass the query condition into your `find` query:

For all users the condition would be: `{}`

```
User.find(<condition>, function(err, users) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(users);
        });
```

But I found that if the collection was created through some method there is a chance that, your `find` might not work. [Mongoose find() not returning result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100328/mongoose-find-not-returning-result/23100950)

This can be the issue. Normal code-wise you are good. I would suggest you to delete of that collection and start by doing inserts from mongoose itself. This will be cleaner

Hope this helps !!

Comment: I still have an empty array as result

Comment: Oh !! Other than this I can't find any issue. Is `users` empty array ?

Comment: `User.find({}, function(err, users) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(users);
        });` Did you do this ?

Comment: Yes and users is still an empty array

Comment: Can you check your db again, to make sure that there are records in it? And are there any exceptions or errors ?

Comment: I've checked it again and there are my 2 records inside. I only have a warning when I'm launching "node app.js" : (node:7771) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181846/discussion-between-vizsatiz-and-ptiflo).

Comment: The `<condition>` argument isn't required. This probably shouldn't have been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this...**

```
User.find({}, function(err, docs) {}
```

Comment: How to return the findings (i.e: a resolver function) ?